# SQL Server 2005 connection to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I having trouble with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I installed it and the service is running but `SQLexpress`, but without success. I even tired to uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 and I could it said that I have cluster node failed.

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post on setting up a SQL Server 2008 R2 Local Database Instance.

[Blog post on Setting up a SQL Server 2008 R2 Local Database Instance](http://www.rtssys.com/blog/archives/14.html)

Start up the Local Server

Click Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> SQL Server Configuration Manager
Set the SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser to automatic start mode.
Right click -> Properties -> Service Tab

**Login to Local Server**

Now open up SQL Server Management Studio and Connect to Object Explorer and select Server Name: [Your PC name]\SQLEXPRESS
Example:  8540P-KL\SQLEXPRESS
To find your PC name:  Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Computer Name tab
Login using windows authentication:  Using the user name [Your Domain]/[Your User Name]

**Setup User Account**

In SQL Mgmt Studio -> Expand your local Server -> Security -> Right click on Logins -> New Login
Uncheck Enforce password policy, password expiration and user must change pw(Since this is local)
Default database -> Your Database
User Mapping Page -> Map to your db and grant db_owner role
Status Page -> Grant Permission to connect and Enable Login

**Setup Access Permissions/Settings for User**

Right click your Local Server -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Enable SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode
Open SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> Enable TCP/IP

**Database Properties File for Spring Project**

database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[local PC Computer name];instance=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=[db name];
database.username=[Your user name]
database.password=[Your password]
database.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver